# Developing Alfresco's server-side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, alfresco, rhino

Alfresco uses [Rhino JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) as server-side scripts implementation with special [Alfresco's Root Objects](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/API-JS-rootscoped.html) and specific method to import other scripts `<import resource="/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Scripts/myscript.js">`.

I have already configured Visual Studio Code and NodeJS with mocked all root objects, so I can test and debug some emulated cases... but this is definitely not enough.

I've found:

- some discussion [how to enable JavaScript debugger](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/177923-javascript-debugger)
- some tutorial how to debug [controller script](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/ws-controller-debug.html).
- [Javascript Console Admin Console component](https://github.com/share-extras/js-console).
- [Rhino Debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Debugger), [Rhino Shell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Shell)

What is recommended by Alfresco developers method to develop server-side JavaScript?

Comment: What isn't working for you with your current development method? What problems are you hitting? Errors? Issues? etc

Comment: my problems for example: differences between NodeJS and Rhino JavaScript (e.g. no prototyping), poor root objects mocking,...

Comment: Are you trying to unit test your code? Or something else?

Comment: yes, I have some unit tests using on my mocked root objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the tools you referenced. I write my Alfresco server-side JavaScript either in the JS console or in Atom, depending on what I'm doing.

If you have a need for anything beyond that you may want to reconsider using JavaScript and instead use Java, Alfresco's native language and foundational API.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, this is also my conclusions, I would just like somebody to confirm. JavaScript should be used for short scripts only. More complex tasks should be implemented as custom java beans, sometimes exposed as JavaScript root objects... Is that a right way?

Comment: Yes, that is my approach. People are free to make their server-side JavaScript as lengthy or complex as they want, obviously, but in my opinion it becomes unwieldy.